# Unexpected execution order in Pytest

Tags: pytest

I'm using `pytest` to do unit testing. I have the logging code on the top of the `calc_test.py` source code:

```
module_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
module_logger.warning(f"Start module:{__name__}, the source file: {__file__}")
```

I expect that every time I run `pytest -vv -s calc_test.py`, the above logging info would show near **the very beginning** of the logs.

To my surprise, this logging never shows up. Even the loggings in `conftest.py` were successfully shown.
I dug into the official documentation, to find any explantion of the execution order for each test file. However there is no mentioning of the loggings at the beginning of each file. My guess is that pytest will put on hold each testing files and first run all the stuff in `conftest.py`. But this isn't confirmed by the documentation.
Very weird, could you explain this behavior?

Comment: I think this is covered [in the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html).

Comment: Especially check the part about [live logs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html#live-logs) - you need something like `--log-cli-level=WARNING`.

Comment: I've gone through the `live logs` section, but it doesn't seems to be the cause. And I already am using the `warning` level. I guess it might has something to do with the location of this `conftest.py` residing inside a package, where the `__init__.py` must be loaded first. I'll keep digging...

Comment: Note that if you don't use `--log-cli-level` (or the respective setting in pytest.ini) nothing will be logged for `logging` calls. `-s` is only to show stdout.